# Issues with pushing large files through Git

Tags: github

Currently when I try to push to a Git repo, I am getting the following error.

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 7bbfe5c1099cfe679aa3cd1eee13e10a
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File e3384023be667de7529538b11c12ec68.201307290946.sql.gz is 125.37 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
```

I have gone through and made sure that this file does not exist in the directory, and have done `git add -u`. We have tried to prune the branch but this doesn't work as it can't find the file to delete.

Comment: no result through commandline with find --name "*.sql.gz" perhaps you have the file in a phpmyadmin directory or some temp directory?

Comment: That didnt seem to find anything either.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is possible that you are pushing several commits, one of them including a large file, and another more recent one *removing* that file.

2020-2022:

Use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (python-based, to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md))

And use some [content-based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_content_based_filtering):

> If you want to filter out all files bigger than a certain size, you can use `--strip-blobs-bigger-than` with some size (`K`, `M`, and `G` suffixes are recognized), e.g.:
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
> ```

---

Original answer, using [obsolete tools like `git filter-branch` or `BFG`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309):

In any case, you can try, as explained in "[Fixing the “this exceeds GitHub’s file size limit of 100 MB” error](http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2013/fixing-the-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-mb-error/)", a filter-branch (if you know the name/path of the large file that you can't see)

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch e3384023be667de7529538b11c12ec68.201307290946.sql.gz' <sha1>..HEAD
```

Or, if you don't know but want to get rid of *any* large file (say > 90MB), you can use the **[BFG repo cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)**

```
bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 90M  my-repo.git
```

That will track for you that elusive large file in your repo history and remove it.
Note that you will have to do a `git push --force` after that, because the history of the more recent commits will have been modified.
If others already cloned your repo before, a bit of communication is in order to warn them.

Comment: Filter branch worked perfectly, cheers for that! All back up and running now.

Comment: Could you clarify what merge-point..HEAD means in your first suggestion? I tried to use it and git said it didn't know what that meant.

Comment: @wandadars that was coming from the article http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2013/fixing-the-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-mb-error/. I replaced "merge-point" by <sha1>: you are meant to filter from that SHA1 (excluded) up to HEAD (included), so take the oldest commit with the file to remove, takes its parent and you will have the sha1 I refer to.

Comment: removing the ` <sha1>..HEAD` was the only way this worked for me.  the error I was getting was `bash: sha1: No such file or directory`

Comment: @ThomasMatthew But... `<sha1>` is supposed to be replaced by an actual commit SHA1.

Comment: How can I do this in Visual Studio Code? thanks

Comment: @Dave Note: I have edited the answer to reference the current tool to use (`git filter-repo`). Second, there is no real integration with VSCode, beside opening a terminal in VSCode and typing the `git filter-repo` command.

Answer (score 31):

In my case I fixed it with this link:

[GitHub Help | Working with large files](http://git.io/iEPt8g)

Notice where it says **giant_file**

```
$ git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch giant_file' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

$ git commit --amend -CHEAD

$ git push
```

Answer (score 11):

Remove file using `filter-branch`

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf your/file/path/task.txt' HEAD
```

make sure you must add `rm -rf`

after that push the code

```
git push origin master -f
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you have several large files you need to run another command:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch largfile1'
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch largefile2'
Cannot create a new backup.
A previous backup already exists in refs/original/
Force overwriting the backup with -f
```

You need to run

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

Then you can run git filter-branch command

Hope this helps you

Comment: Perhaps someone else is aware of a general unmatch command that applies to files over a certain size, but giant_file did not work for my two files. I had to apply the filter-branch command to each of my two large files (running update-ref in between). Thanks to @keminzhou 's suggestion I was able to resolve my large file double commit issue.

Answer (score 3):

Following are the steps with which you can push objects larger than 100MB:

1. Install `git-lfs` instructions can be found at https://git-lfs.github.com/
2. Let say you have `*.jar` files that are larger than 100 MB, then you run `git lfs track "*.jar`. You should see something like

   > Tracking "*.jar"
3. `git add .`
4. `git push -u origin master`

You should see something like:

```
Uploading LFS objects:  89% (398/447), 864 MB | 1.8 MB/s
```

Comment: I've been working on removing multiple larger files from my previous gits and tried multiple ways, this one is the easiest way, thank you!

Comment: Hey! I know this is old but I have a root directory with a zip file (245 MB) in a folder called `downloads`. When using `git-lfs track *.zip`, it shows that it's tracking. When I use `git add .` then `git push -u origin main`, it'll try to commit the large file then say `File [name].zip is 245.90 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB` even though git-lfs is set up. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

First the unstaged commits need to be resolved. Use `git status`

Commit these files

```
git status -s | grep D
```

Commit these files

```
git status -s | grep M
```

and then run this

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path-to-large-file' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Once the above command is executed, the history of commits will be iterated to find the large file and will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download file from:https://git-lfs.github.com/
2. Commands:

a. git lfs install

b. git lfs track "*.psd"

c. git add .gitattributes

3. Commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

I addressed the issue by creating a new branch and adding a `.gitignore` file to exclude Terraform files. After committing these changes, I uploaded the repository again. The problem arose from Git attempting to upload a massive file when running the Terraform project. To resolve this, I created a new repository, added a `.gitignore` file to ignore the folder containing Terraform files. This ensured that only the essential project files, relevant to my work, were uploaded to Git, avoiding unnecessary large file uploads.

Do you get what I mean?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).