# File ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Flutter is 351.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Tags: github, flutter, commit, git-commit

I am trying to push my latest commit to GitHub. But is is showing me following error:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (43/43), completed with 41 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: c8bf146b362d19d128f2ffe74b5b5b9d
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Flutter is 351.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/ChandraPrakashJangid/geo_tags.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Github - File XYZ is 126.80 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349508/github-file-xyz-is-126-80-mb-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-00)? Or this [Git lfs - “this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330771/git-lfs-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-00-mb)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like you're pushing your build folder and other generated files to github. Edit you `.gitignore` file to push only the lib and other necessary files.

a sample flutter `.gitignore` file would look like this

```
    # Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/app/release/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a .gitignore file in your root folder and add the following configs:

```
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/
```

After that save and push to github again