# How to REALLY remove a too large file from git push that was already deleted?

Tags: git, github

On "git push origin master" the following errors occure:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (84/84), completed with 30 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: e6e85fd0a75d9cd592b377a5078084a6
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File releases/release.1.3.5.tar.bz2 is 180.47 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I understand the error, that the file was too large. So i deleted it and tried to pushed again. The same error happens then.

On the internet i've found a possible solution with "git rm --cached filename". But doing this, fails also:

```
$ git rm --cached releases/release.1.3.5.tar.bz2 
fatal: pathspec 'releases/release.1.3.5.tar.bz2' did not match any files
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You'll have to delete all commits which reference the large file. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858590/issues-with-pushing-large-files-through-git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution was:

```
bfg --delete-files release.1.3.5.tar.bz2
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Answer (score 1):

You already committed the file to the git index, and every `git push` will push that commit to the server. You'd have to remove that commit from the history, or rewrite your history to remove that file from all commits that happened since.

See https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/