# GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitignore

I commit the some file and it says

```
remote: error: File models/cifar10_gradcam.h5 is 174.65 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

but I already commit it. how should I reset this commit and add this file to gitignore and recommit?

after I do

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

and re push

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed
>   to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SlowMonk/XAI.git' hint:
>   Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint:
>   'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about
>   fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues with pushing large files through Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858590/issues-with-pushing-large-files-through-git)

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename'
```

Run that and then push. Of course you should replace "filename" with the name of your file.

I found this code on [medium](https://medium.com/@marcosantonocito/fixing-the-gh001-large-files-detected-you-may-want-to-try-git-large-file-storage-43336b983272)

Comment: this destroyed my local repo :(

Answer (score 6):

Suppose the current status is that you've just run `git reset --soft HEAD~1`.

Remove the file from the index,

```
git rm --cached models/cifar10_gradcam.h5
```

Add the file path to gitignore, supposing it's `.gitignore`

```
echo "models/cifar10_gradcam.h5" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
```

Commit the changes,

```
git commit
```

Update the local branch before the push,

```
git pull origin -r master
```

Push the new commit(s),

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Before I saw this answer. I edited .gitignore . Now git rm --cached gives me: fatal : pathspec 'thepath..." did not match any file

Answer (score 4):

You should use Git Large File Storage (git-lfs) as you see your console message.
I try to explain how you should use git-lfs in your project.

Firstly install git-lfs in your homebrew(linux-Mac)

> brew install git-lfs

> git lfs install  //Git LFS initialized.

> git lfs track "*.mp4" //Specify file types to track.

> git add . //Add all changes

> git commit -m "first commit"
> git branch -M main
> git remote add origin yourgithupprojecturl.git
> git push -u origin main

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING: You should have your repo be updated to lastest.**

I know this is probably wrong but this has helped me.

**Situation:** I tried to upload a file that is over 100MB (let's call it file_a), I then delete file_a and tries to `add`, `commit` and `push` again. Git still say that file_a is over 100MB. I then try first:

```
git --reset HEAD~1
```

(I tried multiple times, with the number increased)

When I use push again, git bash prompted me that my index is behind and I need to pull the newest. I then try:

```
git pull my-repo-url
```

After that, I use the normal `add`, `commit` and `push` again. And it worked.